# restricting user input + loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

What I would like to do:

- restrict user input to letters only (lowercase and caps)
- error message on incorrect input
- loop until correct input

Quite a few sites with similar questions suggested regular expressions, patterns, and matchers.  I had at look at the API, and it confused me a lot...

Here's what I tried.

```
public class restrictinput {
    public static void main (String args [] ) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (in);
        System.out.println ("Enter  blah ");
        String blah = sc.nextLine();
        Pattern userInput = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
        Matcher inputCheck = userInput.matcher("blah");
    }
}
```

This compiles, but I'm not sure if it's the correct/best way to do it.  But, if I enter a different character type, it just executes the rest of the code.

How do I only make it execute if the correct character type is received, and what should I use to make the error known to the user?

If the code given is wrong, what should I do to change it?

Comment: You probably mean 'loop until correct input', in which case where is your loop?

Comment: both done. like i said this is new territory for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so there are a couple things here you need to fix. The first thing I noticed is that you want

```
userInput.matcher(blah);
```

not

```
userInput.matcher("blah");
```

because you are matching the string, not just `"blah"`

Now for the bulk of your question. The first thing you need is to look at the [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object. Specifically look into Matcher.find().

The second thing is that you need to add some sort of a conditional loop to your code so that it keeps asking for input. Maybe something like:

```
bool result = true;
do {
    String blah = sc.nextLine();
    Pattern userInput = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    Matcher inputCheck = userInput.matcher("blah");
    result = //boolean check from your matcher object
    if(result) {
        //Complain about wrong input
    }
} while(result);
```

Comment: `bool result = true;
do{
String blah = sc.nextLine();
Pattern userInput = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
Matcher inputCheck = userInput.matcher(blah);
if(false) { System.out.println("wrong input");
} while (true); `

 something like this?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like homework, so I don't want to give away too much, but you want to look into the [if statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) as well as the [while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) or [for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loops.  This will conditionally execute code if certain criteria are met.